# D3 to image on MS Edge

Tags: d3.js, microsoft-edge, canvg

I have the following code and use it to retrieve D3 image for use in a PDF file.  This has been working great until I tried it on Microsoft Edge.  Anybody run across this or have suggestions on how to work around it.  Basically the image comes back with a black center.

```
http://code.google.com/p/canvg/
function getChartImage(chartId: string): string {
"use strict";

var svg: any = document.querySelector("svg");
var svgData: any = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
var canvas: any = document.getElementById("canvas");
var result: any = canvg(canvas, svgData);

return canvas.toDataURL("text/png");
}
```

Top image using IE.  Bottom image using Edge.

[image]

EDIT: Created jsfiddle to test with.  The problem can be seen if you use Edge as the browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/jjhii/46bv10db/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

Because of [a bug in Microsoft Edge](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/2057021/edges-domparser-parsefromstring-converts-known-svg-attributes-to-all-upper-case), it creates many attributes including fill in capital. And canvg doesn’t work properly with that.

**Solution:**

1. Change all of the attribute names (except camel case ones like viewBox and markerWidth) from capital
   to lower case in your svgData
2. There is [a pool request](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg/pull/433) for that in
   canvg. But it doesn’t protect capital B in viewBox and other few camel case attributes. So you can merge
   that pool request by yourself (do an exception in code for viewBox
   if you have any) and use it.

Comment: Yes adding the toLowerCase to the canvg.js file fixed the problem.  I will need to review your other comments and do some testing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the xmlns property: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46bv10db/6/)

```
svg = '<svg id=\"svgId\"
```